# Exclude "deleted" rows when DELETED() is not supported

Tags: sql, coldfusion, dbf

I'm trying to work with some simple DBF files within ColdFusion. I've set up a System DSN in Windows using the dBase driver and have successfully set up the datasource in ColdFusion Administrator. I can do the usual SQL queries against the datasource with no issues.

I've left the "show deleted rows" **on** in the DSN configuration. (The obvious answer is to change that setting, but for now let's pretend that I can't.)

How, then, do I exclude rows marked as deleted in my queries? From information elsewhere, in FoxPro for instance, you'd use the `DELETED()` function to find those rows. However, if I use that function in my CF query I get

> [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] Undefined function 'deleted' in expression.

I've tried these two techniques:

```
SELECT ID, fName, lName, deleted() AS isDeleted
FROM myTable

SELECT ID, fName, lName
FROM myTable
WHERE NOT deleted('myTable')
```

Is there another way to do it that'll work with ColdFusion? Or is the driver setting my only hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, none of the dBase ODBC drivers supports `deleted()` or `SET DELETED ON | OFF`. While changing the setting in the driver configuration would be the best bet, you could also try to use a FoxPro ODBC driver, which should support the deleted() function.

You can also PACK your dBase table, to get rid of your deleted records.

Comment: Where would I find one of these FoxPro drivers? (It's been ages since I had to install a database driver.) How would I pack the dBase table? Assume I don't have access to anything else that reads DBF files.

Comment: If packing the dbf (e.g. deleting records permanently from the table) is an option for you, then I would go with that.  There are lots of shareware and freeware / 30 days test tools available. A quick search brought up this link http://www.allmysoft.com/download_DBF_Viewer_2000_6531.htm FoxPro Drivers can be found on the Microsoft MSDN pages